# How to display popup ads in android application?

Tags: android, popup, admob

Many times i saw in games some ads are displayed like popups or dialogs but i don't know how can i make it ??

I am using admob ads abd display it as banners so could someone tell me how can i make popus ads in games ??

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/adUnitId"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
        ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is an interstitial ad. It is different to a banner ad (which you are using now). You can display both within your app.

Have a look at https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/advanced

Comment: nice that's what i want exactly but i see something called in-app purchase ads. What is this ?

Comment: in-app purchase ads aren't available yet. You can ignore that bit of doco for the moment. They allow you to provide your own ads for sale on in-app pruchases in your app.

Answer (score -1):

Place the AdView on top of your layout. Probably by embedding the content and the AdView in a FrameLayout.

You could also use a real dialog if that is more suitable.

Comment: yes but what about ad design (width and height). is any ad with many dimensions ??